# Refiling to new node in org-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

These are the setting in my .emacs for refiling in org-mode:

```
(setq org-refile-targets (quote ((nil :maxlevel . 10)
                             (org-agenda-files :maxlevel . 10))))

(setq org-refile-use-outline-path t)
(setq org-outline-path-complete-in-steps nil)
(setq org-refile-allow-creating-parent-nodes (quote confirm))
```

Refiling to an existing path works as it should but I can't create a new node and refile to that as the last line should allow me to do. When I refile to a path like:

```
Existing node"/New node"
```

I get the error:

```
Please save the buffer to a file before refiling
```

Supposedly this means that emacs can figure out the target file but the target is set with the `org-refile-targets` line so what's wrong?

Comment: What steps do you take to select the target buffer when attempting to create a new node?

Comment: Well no steps besides the first line in the snippet above. I've attempted pressing C-c-C-w on a node and the typing the refiling path in the same way as when refiling to existing nodes except that I put the node to be created in quotes. I've also tried currentfile.org/Existing node"/New node" but the file name isn't available from autocomplete.

Comment: I was not able to get that feature to work either -- perhaps wait a day or so to see if anyone here can resolve the issue, and then (if no resolution) file a bug report to the org-mode team.

Comment: Would the best way to file a bug report be  `M-x org-submit-bug-report RET`?

Comment: Yes, `M-x org-submit-bug-report RET` is the best method of reaching the org-mode team for bugs.  In addition to fully describing the problem in your e-mail, you might also want to include a link to this thread.

Comment: Is this still a problem? My attempts to reproduce it were unsuccessful but the code has changed a bit in the last two years. If you **can** reproduce it , could you give a complete recipe? Are you refiling to the same file or a different file? BTW, I don't think you should use double quotes when specifying the new node, but maybe I misunderstand exactly what you are doing.

Comment: I am having this issue. Anyone has been able to solve it? Can't create new headings.